Dice game (convolution of binomial distribution)
Consider a game where every round you roll N dice. A running sum of the number of 6s rolled is tabulated, and the game is over when the running sum hits or goes over K. How many rounds on average would this take? I’ve solved this with a Markov chain but was wondering if there was a more closed form solution. Any help appreciated.

We can couple it with another experiment, where in each round, you roll a die, and you want to count the number of rounds needed to get at least $K$ $6$'s. Let this number be $X$, then the number of rounds needed for your original question is simply $\lceil X/N\rceil$.
Now the distribution of $X$ is easy to compute: its generating function is
$$f(x) = \left(\frac{x}{6-5x}\right)^K,$$
and $\mathbb{E}[X] = 6K$. It is also clear that
$$\mathbb{E}[\lceil X/N\rceil] = \frac{1}{N}\mathbb{E}[X]+\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}(N-i)\mathbb{P}(X\equiv i\mod N).$$
For each $i$, the probability may be computed as
$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}\zeta^{-ij}f(\zeta^j)$$
where $\zeta$ is a primitive $N$-th root of unity.
Therefore we can also write the sum as
$$\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}\left((N-i)\zeta^{-ij}\right)f(\zeta^j).$$
The inner sum is exactly equal to
$$\frac{\zeta^{-(n-1)j}+\cdots +\zeta^{-2j}-(N-1)\zeta^{-j}}{1-\zeta^j}=-\frac{N\zeta^{-j}}{1-\zeta^{-j}}=\frac{N}{1-\zeta^j}.$$
Hence
$$\mathbb{E}[\lceil X/N\rceil] = \frac{6K}{N}+\frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}\frac{\zeta^{jK}}{(1-\zeta^j)(6-5\zeta^j)^K}.$$
It's quite possible that this can be further simplified as well.

Thank you for the help. Would this lead to the same answer regardless of what nth root of unity is used? Assuming 1 cannot be used as it would put a factor of 0 in the denominator in the sum?

As long as $\xi$ is a primitive $N$-th root of unity, it leads to the same answer.
